# Update Table1 adding values from Table2

Tags: sql-server

```
  Table1
  Columns     PK_Table1   Name | DoYouGoToSchool |DoYouhaveACar |DoYouWorkFullTime | DoYouWorkPartTime  |  Score
                1          joe     Yes               Yes              No                   Yes   
                2          amy     No                Yes              Yes                  No    



 Table2      
  Columns     Pk_Table2   |Question                   | Answer(Bit Column)   |Value 
                1          DoYouGoToSchool              True                   3
                2          DoYouhaveACar                True                   2                
                3          DoYouWorkFullTime            True                   4
                4          DoYouWorkPartTime            True                   2
```

Based on the information from Table2 What i need to do is UPDATE Table1 ColumnName Score by summing up the Value from Table2 with the information he has provided.

```
        for example i expect the Score column in table1 to be 7 for record 1 
                                                        and   5 for record 2
```

Here is a query to play with

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table2') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Table2
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Table1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Table1

GO

create table #Table1
(
    PK_Table1               int, 
    Name            Varchar(50), 
    DoYouGoToSchool  Varchar(8),
    DoYouhaveACar    Varchar(8),
    DoYouWorkFullTime Varchar(8),
    DoYouWorkPartTime Varchar(8),
    Score             INT NULL,
)

create table #Table2
(
    PK_Table2               int, 
    Questions      Varchar(50), 
    Answer         BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT(0),
     VALUE         INT NULL 
)


INSERT INTO #Table1 (Name,DoYouGoToSchool,DoYouhaveACar,DoYouWorkFullTime,DoYouWorkPartTime)
VALUES ('joe','Yes','Yes','No','Yes'), ('amy','NO','Yes','Yes','No')
INSERT INTO #Table2(Questions,Answer,VALUE)
VALUES ('DoYouGoToSchool','True',3 ),('DoYouhaveACar','True',2 ),('DoYouWorkFullTime','True',4 ),('DoYouWorkPartTime','True',2 )
```

This is what is missing from answer below that tells you to create new FK contraint to the Table2 --Inserting Data into the table with the new FK Column

```
insert into #Table2 (FK_Table1, Questions, Answer) select t.PK_Table1, t1.cols, colsval from #Table1 t cross apply (values (PK_Table1,'DoYouGoToSchool', DoYouGoToSchool), (PK_Table1,'DoYouhaveACar', DoYouhaveACar), (PK_Table1,'DoYouWorkFullTime', DoYouWorkFullTime), (PK_Table1,'DoYouWorkPartTime', DoYouWorkPartTime) ) t1 (PK_Table1,cols, colsval);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a relation between these two tables and add Primary key of Table1 in Table2 as a foreign key so your Table2 becomes:

```
Table2 Columns:     
FK_Table1    |Pk_Table2   |Question                   | Answer(Bit Column)   |Value 
    1           1          DoYouGoToSchool              True                   3
    1           2          DoYouhaveACar                True                   2
    1           3          DoYouWorkFullTime            True                   4
    1           4          DoYouWorkPartTime            True                   2
```

You can add in table by using this Query:

```
ALTER TABLE Table2
    ADD FK_Table1 INTEGER,
    ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY(FK_Table1) REFERENCES Table1(PK_Table1)
```

means that it is only for that person whose PK_Table1 = 1

Then you can extract his score from this query:

```
SELECT Sum(Value) FROM Table2 WHERE FK_Table1 = 1;
```

And then update query:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET score = (enter here the returned score from above query)
WHERE PK_Table1 = 1;
```

Or you can do in a single query like this:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET score = (SELECT Sum(Value) FROM Table2 WHERE FK_Table1 = 1)
WHERE PK_Table1 = 1;
```

Comment: I like this idea not sure if i can add new key into the client table. I will try to implement this logic and get back to you. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sure. You have to make the relation between these 2 tables, otherwise you can't able to do want you want

Comment: @user3920526 Have you checked that or not?

Comment: I wanted to apply this logic, have you thought about how to introduce a new Column ie FK_Table1 in Table2 .  In order to do that i am trying to pivot the data and Insert it into  Table2  with the new Column FK_table1 as per example above. I will let me you know.

Comment: @user3920526 Check the edited answer. I have added the query to create a new column which works as a foreign key in Table2

Comment: I do understand creating a FK , but i need to insert the data in Table2 pivoting the data in table1 right ?

Comment: --This is what is missing 
--Inserting Data into the table with the new FK Column  
 
insert into #Table2 (FK_Table1, Questions, Answer)
select t.PK_Table1, t1.cols, colsval
from #Table1 t cross apply 
        (values (PK_Table1,'DoYouGoToSchool', DoYouGoToSchool), 
                (PK_Table1,'DoYouhaveACar', DoYouhaveACar), 
                (PK_Table1,'DoYouWorkFullTime', DoYouWorkFullTime), 
                (PK_Table1,'DoYouWorkPartTime', DoYouWorkPartTime)
        ) t1 (PK_Table1,cols, colsval);

Comment: For that, you have to remove the data from your Table2 and insert that again

Comment: Yes table 2 is a lookup for Table1 sorry i might have missed some details but thank you for this idea . If you can copy paste my last comment into your answer it will help other people also . Thank you

Comment: @user3920526 I am glad you liked the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add another table.  This table will be your relational table.  It can be called Table1_Table2 with three columns. The first column will be the primary key for the table.  The next column will be the primary key of Table1 and the third column will be the primary key for Table 2.

When an instance of Table2 occurs that relates with Table1, insert a record into Table1_Table2 that relates the two tables together with each others primary key.  Then a query can be done on the relational table, Table1_Table2 that allows you to sum the relationships.

`|Table1_Table2 |
|  PK  |  PK_Table1  | PK_Table2  |
|  1   |     1       |     1      |
|  2   |     1       |     3      |
|  3   |     2       |     1      |
|  4   |     2       |     4      |`

As we can see, we can now perform an update on Table1

`UPDATE TABLE1 A SET A.SCORE = (Select SUM(B.Value) FROM Table2 B, Table1_Table2 C  WHERE C.PK_Table2 = B.PK_Table2 AND C.PK_Table1 = A.PK_Table1);`